# How to use Primary key in Realm in iOS (Objective c)

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, primary-key, realm

I Declared email as primary key in a Realm model.

```
+ (NSString *)primaryKey
{
   return @"email";
}


- (void)insertUserWithFirstName:(NSString*)firstname lastName:     (NSString*)lastname email:(NSString*)email address:(NSString*)address gender:(NSString*)gender mobile:(NSString*)mobile department:(NSString*)department
{
   RLMRealm *realm = [RLMRealm defaultRealm];
   [realm beginWriteTransaction];

   Employee *employeeInfo = [[Employee alloc]init];
   employeeInfo.firstName = firstname;
   employeeInfo.lastName = lastname;
   employeeInfo.email = email;
   employeeInfo.address = address;
   employeeInfo.gender = gender;
   employeeInfo.mobile = mobile;
   employeeInfo.department = department;

   [realm addObject:employeeInfo];
   [realm commitWriteTransaction];
}
```

After entering a duplicate email app crashes.

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'RLMException', reason: 'Can't set primary key property 'email' to existing value .

How to user Primary key in Realm?

How to prevent this crash?

Please help me.

Comment: put some code ... where does crash occurs put that code

Comment: You have to handle that exception with try...catch

Comment: Actually i need a response like "Email already exist". But app crash reason with  'Can't set primary key property 'email' to existing value .

Comment: catch (NSException *exception)
    {
        NSLog(@"email already exists in Database");
        if ([realm inWriteTransaction])
        {
            [realm cancelWriteTransaction];
        }
    }


catch part not executing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use try... catch to handle exception like

```
    RLMRealm *realm = [RLMRealm defaultRealm];
    @try {
             [realm beginWriteTransaction];

             Employee *employeeInfo = [[Employee alloc]init];
             employeeInfo.firstName = firstname;
             employeeInfo.lastName = lastname;
             employeeInfo.email = email;
             employeeInfo.address = address;
             employeeInfo.gender = gender;
             employeeInfo.mobile = mobile;
             employeeInfo.department = department; 
             [realm addObject:employeeInfo];  // [realm addOrUpdateObject:employeeInfo];
             [realm commitWriteTransaction];
     }
     @catch (NSException *exception) {
         NSLog(@"exception");
         if ([realm inWriteTransaction]) {
            [realm cancelWriteTransaction];
         }
     }
```

As suggested by @Konstantin, you can also use `[realm addOrUpdateObject:employeeInfo];` to update your data with primary key...

Comment: Ok @Bhavin.i will do it.

Answer (score 1):

Primary key means that this is unique key though all entities. If keys are not unique, Realm crashes.

That is documentation:
*Override +primaryKey to set the model’s primary key. Declaring a primary key allows objects to be looked up and updated efficiently and enforces uniqueness for each value. Once an object with a primary key is added to a Realm, the primary key cannot be changed.*

In your case it's better to create new entity in realm and do migration to this new entity.

Or you can just do dirty hack: add new property and write emails in it, and in email (which is Primary Key) write any unique value.

Comment: Also you could use `[realm addOrUpdateObject:employeeInfo];`
 instead of just adding object incase if email is really unique and you should update info

Comment: i don't want to update Employee info. i want to know email exist in DB.

Comment: Then just check if email exists in Realm before adding. But it looks like not so good architectural move. In future you may face off more serious problems.